# Pandas vectorized string methods, named capture

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Apologies in advance if I misformat or otherwise mangle my question...

I'm new to pandas (and python) and have been slowly working my way trying to apply things learned to my own datasets.

I have a sparse dataframe of grants data where many of the cells are nulls (or equivalent), many of which should be able to be rid of through normalization.  Additionally, project numbers contains within each, information that could be used to validate other separately provided fields (year, grantor, research activity, etc...).

The project numbers look like this:

```
0             None,
1             None,
2     3C06RR018774,
3     3C06RR018774,
4     1C06RR018796,
5     1C06RR018796,
6     3C06RR018863,
7     3C06RR018863,
8     1C06RR020099,
9     1C06RR020099,
10    1C06RR020117,
```

And the regex I composed looks like:

```
reobj = re.compile(r"""
(?P<type>[0-9]+)
(?P<act>[A-Z]+[0-9]+)
(?P<ic>[A-Z]{2})
(?P<serial>[0-9]{1,6})""",
flags=re.X)
```

Which I'm pretty sure works because this:

```
m = core.str.match(reobj)
```

Gives:

```
0                     None
1                     None
2     (3, C06, RR, 018774)
3     (3, C06, RR, 018774)
4     (1, C06, RR, 018796)
5     (1, C06, RR, 018796)
6     (3, C06, RR, 018863)
7     (3, C06, RR, 018863)
8     (1, C06, RR, 020099)
9     (1, C06, RR, 020099)
10    (1, C06, RR, 020117)
```

However I am neither able to fetch out the groups, m.groups():

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'groups'
```

Nor can I seem to dig out the parsed bits, m.str.get(1):
I also get the same error with m.str[0]

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-2a7675586aff> in <module>()
----> 1 m.str.get(1)

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/strings.pyc in get(self, i)
    668     @copy(str_get)
    669     def get(self, i):
--> 670         result = str_get(self.series, i)
    671         return self._wrap_result(result)
    672 

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/strings.pyc in str_get(arr, i)
    551     """
    552     f = lambda x: x[i]
--> 553     return _na_map(f, arr)
    554 
    555 

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/strings.pyc in _na_map(f, arr, na_result)
     87 def _na_map(f, arr, na_result=np.nan):
     88     # should really _check_ for NA
---> 89     return _map(f, arr, na_mask=True, na_value=na_result)
     90 
     91 

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/strings.pyc in _map(f, arr, na_mask, na_value)
     96         mask = isnull(arr)
     97         try:
---> 98             result = lib.map_infer_mask(arr, f, mask.view(np.uint8))
     99         except (TypeError, AttributeError):
    100             def g(x):

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/lib.so in pandas.lib.map_infer_mask (pandas/lib.c:39584)()

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/strings.pyc in <lambda>(x)
    550     items : array
    551     """
--> 552     f = lambda x: x[i]
    553     return _na_map(f, arr)
    554 

IndexError: list index out of range
```

However, m.str[:1] does dig out:

```
0     None
1     None
2      (3)
3      (3)
4      (1)
5      (1)
6      (3)
7      (3)
8      (1)
9      (1)
10     (1)
```

I think my primary misunderstanding is in the iteration of the compiled match object over the series but at the end of the day, I'd like to be able to compare each group to another field within the same row to internally validate the dataset:

```
m.group('ic') == data['IC']
```

although ideally being able to compare all captured groups at once in array-like fashion across rows...

Any guidance, or even just a healthy shove in the right direction, would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Would you be okay with using a `map` on the columns?

Comment: I'm just tickled to learn and move forward- anyway to get the job done at the moment is fine, and as it's cross-validating and thus only needs to be done once, it doesn't even have to be particularly speedy.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`str.match` is returning a tuple, not the `match` objects:

```
>>> c.str.match(reobj)
0                      []
1                      []
2    (3, C06, RR, 018774)
3    (3, C06, RR, 018774)
Name: 1
>>> type(c.str.match(reobj)[2])
<type 'tuple'>
```

We can get them, though:

```
>>> m = c.map(reobj.match)
>>> m
0                                    None
1                                    None
2    <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xa1f4c28>
3    <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xa05aee8>
Name: 1
```

And with them, although it's a little ugly, we can get a `Series` to compare with `data["IC"]`:

```
>>> m.map(lambda x: x.group("ic") if x else None)
0    None
1    None
2      RR
3      RR
Name: 1
```

Note that the groups are also stored in `groupindex`:

```
>>> reobj.groupindex
{'ic': 3, 'type': 1, 'serial': 4, 'act': 2}
```

and so you can loop over them programmatically.  Anyway, HTH.

Comment: I can follow the first part, returning the tuple, but m = c.map(reobj.match) throws:  TypeError: expected string or buffer. c is my series of project numbers.  Still stuck, but very much appreciate the help- never would have figured any of this out on my own.